# Mail Queue and DOMPDF job works perfectly on homestead, but not on my production server

Tags: laravel, laravel-5.1

Latest 5.1 Laravel 5.1.27 
Latest dompdf 0.6.2

So i have an email, that attaches a generated PDF, that is queued.

Tested on homestead, both manually with artisan:work and artisen:listen, it all works well, i receive the email perfectly with the attached PDF.

Only in my production server, that has same parameters, at least for what i can see, doesnt work!!

It all works if synchronously with Mail::send

When updated to Mail:queue, i get the Job stuck, on production i have supervisor with artisan:listen --tries=10 and it gets failed, and moved to the failed_jobs table.

Aah, mail::queue workes perfectly if without PDF attachment

So i could nail it down to the exception thrown by DOMPDF, only in production and only in a queued job!

```
exception 'ErrorException' with message 'Undefined index: SCRIPT_FILENAME' in /home/myapp_name/vendor/dompdf/dompdf/include/stylesheet.cls.php:147
```

So this line on stylesheet.cls.php:147 is

```
list($this->_protocol, $this->_base_host, $this->_base_path) = explode_url($_SERVER["SCRIPT_FILENAME"]);
```

So all comes down to being on CLI (command line interface), that doesn't have this $_SERVER["SCRIPT_FILENAME"] defined!!

All would make sense to go down this road, but why the heck does it work perfectly when job processed in homestead, also on CLI??

Hope i make sense!!
Code for the queue

```
$data = [bla bla bla]; // this $data is for the blade render, and is different from the one used in the Closure, for the PDF, i know =)
    Mail::queue('emails.default', $data , function($message) use ($destinatarios, $user_spo_full_name, $spare_part_order, $spare_parts_order_list)
    {
        $message->to($destinatarios);
        $message->subject('Spare Part Order Confirmation - Your ref: ' . $spare_part_order->client_reference );

        $data =
            [
                'user_full_name' => $user_spo_full_name,
                'spare_part_order' => $spare_part_order,
                'spare_parts_order_list' => $spare_parts_order_list
            ];
        $pdf = PDF::loadView('spareparts.sparepartsorder.pdf.spare-part-order', compact('data'));
        $message->attachData($pdf->output(), 'SP_'.$spare_part_order->client_reference . '.pdf' );

    });
```

Thanks in advance for any help and happy new year all!!

Comment: can you post your composer.json file ? if you write down them under require-dev it might the problem.

Comment: Sure, now not at work, but i guess is no related to any packages on require dev, since all works if just changing Mail::queue to Mail::send .... Of course that would make it run synchronously, and take 10 times longer (sending email)!

Comment: If it works on one server but not the other, then it's probably a difference in configuration between the two. Some things to look at: environment variables, `.env` files, `composer.json`, your Laravel config files, config files for any packages (maybe you've forgotten to publish one?)

Answer (score 3):

Got it!!

On the production server, there is the queue:listen process running with supervisor.

So that's it, when we ssh into the server, and if we run php -i , we can see the $_SERVER variables were loaded, even as blank.

When the php command is run via supervisor, there is no $_SERVER variables.

So the solution to get DOMPDF working within the queue processed by supervisor, is to workaround the code. if you have it through composer, like me, it will be a pain, forking the repository, and changing the source in composer.json

Then, all we have to do is working the logs until all environemnt variables are met, through

```
if (!issset($_SERVER["SCRIPT_FILENAME"])) $_SERVER["SCRIPT_FILENAME"] = "";
```

This will make it work, as it does when running through SSH, that's how it loads the vars, empty!

Hope this helps anyone!!

Comment: Yeah, this works, in latest version of dompdf/dompdf I only had to update Css/Stylesheet.php file and it works. Thanks

Comment: Glad it helped!!

Comment: I have a related issue in PHPUnit testing - as there is no SCRIPT_FILENAME and PHP_SELF set, the laravel route(); functions that work well on my local WAMP stack using a browser fail in phpUnit Tests because my Lavavel is installed locally in a ```myapp``` subfolder (I access it via ```http://localhost/myapp``` rather than ```http://localhost/``` and this is unsupported by laravel. PHPUnit test that use route('myRouteName'); return incorrect values if APP_URL has a path component due to absense of PHP_SELF and SCRIPT_FILENAME